# Exception: "could not set a field value by reflection setter"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When I try to read written data from hibernate database I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of familyTree.data.Data1.bio
```

This is class for saving my data with constructor, I pasted important part from it:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="DATA.PERSON")
public class Data1 {



    @Id 
    @Column(name = "ID") 
    @GeneratedValue 
    private int id;

...

    @Column(name = "BIO")
    public final String bio;

...

    public Data1(String names, Integer dayBirth, Integer monthBirth, Integer yearBirth, String bio, String fileID) {
        this.names = names;
        this.dayBirth = dayBirth;
        this.monthBirth = monthBirth;
        this.yearBirth = yearBirth;
        this.bio = bio;
        this.fileID = fileID;
    }

...

    public String getBiog() {
        return bio;
    }
```

So, when I try to do this:

```
data = new Data1(names, dayBirth, monthBirth, yearBirth, bio, fileID);
                                fireActionPerformed();

                            DatabaseUtils.spremiRezultatTesta(data);

                            List<?> podaci = DatabaseUtils.dohvatiRezultateTestova();

                            String ffff = podaci.get(0).toString(); 

                            System.out.print(ffff);
```

I get mentioned exception. Any help?

Database entity for that is created like this: `BIO VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL`and I can normally read it with SELECT FROM query in database.

Here is my DatabaseUtils class, used for saving and loading from database, if needed:

```
public class DatabaseUtils {

    public static void spremiRezultatTesta(Data1 data) { 
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernatePersistenceUnit"); 
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
        em.getTransaction().begin(); 
        em.persist(data); 
        em.getTransaction().commit(); 
        } 

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
        public static List<Data1> dohvatiRezultateTestova() { 
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernatePersistenceUnit"); 
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
        Query query = em.createQuery("FROM Data1"); 
        return query.getResultList();
        }


}
```

Comment: Hmm. What do you think the `final` keyword does?

Comment: Did you tried with PostgreSQL?

Comment: `Final` keyword doesn't allow later changes...

Comment: @eruiz, no, have no experience with PostgreSQL. You think it can help me?

Comment: It even prevents reflectional changes, so Hibernate cannot set this property.

Comment: O, ok, I'll try to go with `public string bio` then.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. :) Stupid mistake.

Only thing... now I get values on console, just not right ones.

I get this: familyTree.data.Data1@18fe28cf